# Is the sentence "I think you should capitalize formal titles before a name" grammatically correct?

Tags: american-english, parallelism

> I think you should capitalize formal titles before **a name**.

or

> I think you should capitalize formal titles before **names**.

Regardless of the above statement is true or not, my question is should I use **a name** or **names**?
What I want to express is that you should capitalize titles like: **Doctor** Johnson, **Uncle** Robert, **Mr.** Johnson, **President** Johnson, etc.

I am confused. Should I use names because "formal titles" is plural? I think I should use "a name" because it sounds right.

What part of the grammar should I look to learn more about it? There must be a name that I can use to search more about the topic.

Comment: You can use either. In some religious and royal contexts, individuals can have several titles. Zulu praise singers have as many titles for a chief as the Catholic Church has in a litany of the Virgin Mary. For what it's worth, in a number of European languages it's also common for such double honorifics as *Professor Doctor* and *Doctor Architect/Lawyer/You name it*.

Comment: To add onto what @RonaldSole is saying, there are defined order in which titles go, though usually only people from the UK take it seriously. But if someone for example, is knighted, and has a PhD, and is a professor, you might impress them very much by knowing how to properly address them (IIRC, Sir, Professor, Dr. TheirName)

Comment: I would go with "a name," but there is an argument for "names." It all depends on what you want to say. Although unlikely, "names" could imply that this condition only applies when there are a plural number of names, such as "Doctor John Smith" or "Doctors John and James." Meanwhile, "a name" would not have this implication. Would just let you know, any time you see a name, you should capitalize the formal title preceding it.

Answer (score 1):

"Capitalize titles before a name" explicitly takes care of the situation where there is more than one tile before a name. For example, Prof. Dr. Dr. Smith and not Prof. dr. dr. Smith. That's why a would prefer to write it this way.

Now the question was: "Is it grammatically correct"? Both versions are correct, but that is meaningless when they express (slightly) different things. The grammar is not the problem, the semantics is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the words "I think", unless  you are unsure that you are correct.  "I think" qualifies your statement.

Others may not agree because we hear it in speech all the time. However, in writing, we still hold ourselves to higher standards for clarity, unless it is speech used in  a novel or reported as a quote. "I think that the Earth revolves around the sun." This would be declarative if it was not yet proven. It would be the speaker's opinion, not a statement of fact.

As to plurals, they are confusing. You used the plural correctly in your sample.

I prefer, but either will work:

> You should capitalize titles before names.

**M**r. Smith, **D**octor Jones, **P**resident Smith, **R**everend Jones are examples of this.